# WPF RichTextBox Span changes to Run

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Please help me understand the result of this operation.

I have a simple test application which contain the following XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Span x:Name="def" Tag="default">
                    <Run>asd</Run>
                </Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="tx" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

I have the following in code behind.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rtb.TextChanged += Rtb_TextChanged;

}
private void Rtb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tx.Text = XamlWriter.Save(rtb.Document);
}
```

When I run this code, and type some letters in the above `RichTextBox`, below textbox shows me the xaml.

Strangely, it loses the span and it converts to run.

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Paragraph>as
        <Run xml:lang="en-in" xml:space="preserve"> </Run> d
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

I am not able to control the change of this span to run.
I need help with that.

Comment: You're overriding the content in the `<Paragraph>` object when you type. It's just doing what you're asking it to do. It was a nested object with a `<Span>` containing a `<Run>`. Your new (manually entered) content only consists of a `Run`.

Comment: So, is there a way I direct it into the span rather than manually overriding it?

Comment: One way I know is to override key events and append text. But thats very tedious. Another way I keep a hiddent ui element and it doesnt change. But I feel those are not accurate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example to see the difference:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Span x:Name="def" Tag="default">
                        <Run>asd</Run>
                    </Span>
                </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Span x:Name="def1" Tag="default">
                    <Run Foreground="Red">asd</Run>
                    <Run>new</Run>
                </Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="tx" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Row="2" Click="tx_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

It contains two kinds of paragraphs. One with a simple Run, which is removed by `Save` method, and the other which has Foreground property, which is not removed (Check this by clicking the Button)

(Edit) in code behind:

```
    private void tx_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tx.Text = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(rtb.Document);
    }
```